# html2canvas Capture a chart.js-Chart with the size of full screen on different window size

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, chart.js, html2canvas

I want to generate a PDF with images created by html2canvas. The base component on my website is the following: [image: Base Component]

The generated PDF on a fullscreen browser looks like this:[image: Generated PDF]

If I resize the window the component now looks for example like this [image: Resized Base Component]

And the PDF now looks like this:[image: Generated PDF with resized Component]

My problem is that I want the two charts to look the same in the PDF, no matter which window size you are using. The text already gets rendered correctly because I added `windowHeight: "1080px", windowWidth: "1920px"` as options to html2canvas like this:

```js
let dataURL;
await html2canvas(document.getElementById(id), {
  windowHeight: "1080px",
  windowWidth: "1920px",
}).then(canvas => 
  dataURL = canvas.toDataURL()
)
return dataURL
```

Somehow the charts are not changing their size according to that.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1:

(Can't add comment, so listing potential solution as answer)
I had similar problem at my work. This is how I solved it:

1. Collect each of the charts as sperate images, by converting to base64 and saving them.
2. Have a pdf with predefined layout, using pdf parser place these images in predetermined spots.

This way the pdf would always look the same.

Looks, you have data too... you can collect each of them in a json and again write the info using the PDF parser.

Solution 2:

When the user click on 'Print/Save as PDF:'

1. Open same page in a new window with predetermined height/width (in which everything looks alright).
2. Trigger Print after this was fully loaded.

This way your pdf will always look the same.

Comment: I don't understand how "Solution 1" should solve my problem. The conversion into base64 doesn't resize my chart. It would look the same as it looked above, in the 4th picture. I think "Solution 2" would work generally but in my specific case I can't open a second page. Mainly because of performance and the login on this page. I don't see any other option but manually resizing the charts before rendering, but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Create a hidden div (display:none) just below this dashboard with a chartjs canvas, on user clicking print, render all these charts in this hidden canvas and convert to picture, one by one and then render to pdf using any js-pdf solution. 
I have more workable ideas if you would like!

Comment: Could you please provide a code example? I tried to clone the charts into hidden divs, which have the correct size. In the html2canvas-onclone function, I set the display property to "block" to show the chart and let html2canvas render it. But if I do so, in the PDF nothing gets displayed, and in my browser console is a warning which says my canvas is tainted: `Unable to clone canvas as it is tainted <canvas height=​"0" style=​"display:​ block;​ box-sizing:​ border-box;​ height:​ 0px;​ width:​ 0px;​" width=​"0">​`

Comment: Can you please provide me a stackblitz/codepen link, so that I have something to work with?

Comment: Was this resolved?